# How do I change the port in debug mode in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, node.js, debugging, v8, nodeclipse

I am trying to debug a node.js project in Eclipse, running the code locally.
I choose "debug as node.js project", but I cannot seem to change the port from the default.
In other words I want to run this:

```
node --debug-brk=3000 C:\Users\denman\workspaceNonAndroid\XXXNodeXXX\app.js
```

instead of this:

```
node --debug-brk=5858 C:\Users\denman\workspaceNonAndroid\XXXNodeXXX\app.js
```

on a related note - can I run those commands from the command line and see a debugging session in Eclipse, perhaps? How do I run those commands from within Eclipse?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Windows -> Preferences -> Nodeclipse
change what is configured for debug port

Read more on http://www.nodeclipse.org/ and in built-in help with <kbd>F1</kbd>